# How did the author of Mahabarata know the exact conversation between Krishna and arjuna?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

The conversation entices an entire song, the bhagavad ghita, it is so elaborate and intricate, how can someone who was not part of that conversation know every word of it exactly as it happened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many people listened to the Bhagavad Gita in the Mahabharata along with Arjuna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/866/how-many-people-listened-to-the-bhagavad-gita-in-the-mahabharata-along-with-arju)

Comment: So basically sanyaja is the third party here, so he remembered every word of it exactly, how?

Comment: The way I understand it is basically Sanjaya listened so he could remember the basic summary , but since nothing really new is said in the ghita given how it is written that the author actually expresses the entirety if uphanishades through the ghita

Comment: Plus I don't trust anything that links or refers iskcon hare Krishna

Comment: OK so basically there was also the fourth party there, but not materially, The author himself, who who saw and heard the conversation

Comment: The Lord wanted another person to hear the conversation and remember it so it would become available as a teaching to mankind.

Answer (score 2):

Sage Vyasa had the ascetic power due to which he could see/listen everything that transpired in the Mahabharata war zone.

We should not forget that it was [Sage Vyasa, who gave the boon](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/m06002.htm) to Sanjaya that the latter will narrate every minute detail to Dhritarashtra.

> "Vyasa said,--'O king, thy sons and the other monarchs have their hour
>   arrived. 2 Mustered in battle they will kill one another. O Bharata,
>   their hour having come, they will all perish. Bearing in mind the
>   changes brought on by time, do not yield thy heart to grief. O king,
>   if thou wish to see them (fighting) in battle, I will, O son, grant
>   thee vision. Behold the battle."
>
> "Dhritarashtra said,--'O best of regenerate Rishi, I like not to
>   behold the slaughter of kinsmen. I shall, however, through thy potency
>   hear of this battle minutely."
>
> Vaisampayana continued.--
>
> "Upon his not wishing to see the battle but wishing to hear of it,
>   Vyasa, that lord of boons, gave a boon to Sanjaya. (And addressing
>   Dhritarashtra he said),--
>
> 'This Sanjaya, O king, will describe the battle to thee. ***Nothing in
>   the whole battle will be beyond this one's eyes***.' Endued, O king
>   with celestial vision, Sanjaya will narrate the battle to thee.
>
> He will have knowledge of everything. Manifest or concealed,
>   (happening) by day or by night, even that which is thought of in the
>   mind, Sanjaya shall know everything. Weapons will not cut him and
>   exertion will not fatigue him. This son of Gavalgani will come out of
>   the battle with life.
>
> As regards myself, O bull of Bharata's race, the fame of these Kurus,
>   as also of all the Pandavas, I will spread. Do not grieve. This is
>   destiny, O tiger among men. It behoveth thee not to give way to grief.
>   It is not capable of being prevented. As regards victory, it is there
>   where righteousness is.'"

Comment: OK so to clarify vaisampayana is vyasa the writer of the ghita?

Comment: Vaisampayana is one of the disciples of Sage Vyasa

Comment: When Sanjaya could see everything that occurs in the battlefield,  with the blessing of Sage Vyasa, can't  Sage Vyasa do the same for narrating the same?  It is implied. @sv.