# Did Hanumanji listen to the Bhagavad Gita?Did He “require” the essence of the Bhagavad Gita as such?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, bhagavad-gita, hanuman, arjuna

It is known that Hanumanji placed himself on the flag of Arjuna’s chariot during the Kurukshetra war;if so,Did Hanumanji also listen to the Bhagavad Gita?

Comment: does this ans. the question   https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/866/how-many-people-listened-to-the-bhagavad-gita-in-the-mahabharata-along-with-arju

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many people listened to the Bhagavad Gita in the Mahabharata along with Arjuna?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/866/how-many-people-listened-to-the-bhagavad-gita-in-the-mahabharata-along-with-arju)

Answer (score 2):

Well I think, hanumanji never needed to listen as, he had learnt from his aradhya bhagwan shri Ramchandra, bhagwati mata adijagatjanni Sita, ramanuj shri laxman ji.
There are as many as ramayan and nobody knows how many ram gita were once present on the surface of the earth.
**At present there are 5 ram gita

1. From adhyātām Rāmāyan
2. From adbhut Ramayan
3. From aadi ramayan
4. From vasisht sarayan
5. From Skand Puran nirvan khand**